# SQL Error - Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, spring-jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am creating a temporary table for some purpose, I get the following error:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect
> syntax near '@P0'.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
>
> ```
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505) 
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
>
>    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:328)
>
>    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:102)
>
>    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>
>    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:194)
> ```

I read that someone encountered the same issue and was able to resolve it by changing the dialect, SQLServer2008Dialect to SQLServer2012Dialect. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Can anyone help me out?

```
    private void dropTempTable(Session session, String tableName) {
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery("drop table ?");
    query=query.setParameter(1,tableName);
    query.executeUpdate();
}

private void createTempTable(Session session, String tableName) {
    Query query=session.createSQLQuery("create table ?" + " (" +
            "ID numeric(19,0) not null, " +
            "COM_ID numeric(19,0) not null, " +
            "SESSIONID varchar(256) not null, " +
            "TIME numeric(19,0) not null)");
    query=query.setParameter(1,tableName);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: What is the actually executed query? Like the output of `query.executeUpdate();`

Comment: First I’ll call the createtemptable method so the create table query has to be executed after that I’ll perform some stuffs and then I drop that table. For both query getting an incorrect syntax error exception..

Comment: Like I answered on the Hibernate discourse forum (https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sql-error-caused-by-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-incorrect-syntax-near-p0/7235) already, you can't use parameters for DDL statements like create table.